# Application Services IsLoggedInAsync() always returns false

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have a legacy application that uses a custom Membership provider.

Following the following tutorial / https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/bb515342(v=vs.100)#exposing-the-application-services / I added Wcf Application Services to the application.

Then I created a Web API, which calls the Wcf services.

There is an Authentication Service, which I call in the following way:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] UserLogin user)
{
    bool result = false;

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(user.userName) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(user.password))
    {
        return NotFound(result);
    }

    CookieContainer? cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    string customCredential = "Not used by the default membership provider.";

    // Authentication ticket remains valid across sessions.
    bool isPersistent = true;

    using (new OperationContextScope(AuthenticationServiceClient.InnerChannel))
    {
        try
        {
            result = await AuthenticationServiceClient.LoginAsync(user.userName, user.password,
                customCredential, isPersistent);
            cookieContainer = GetCookies(OperationContext.Current);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex.Message);
            if (ex.InnerException != null)
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
        }

        if (result)
        {
            var response =
                (HttpResponseMessageProperty)OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties[
                    HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name];
            SharedCookie = response.Headers["Set-Cookie"];
            if (SharedCookie != null)
            {
                HttpContext.Session.SetString(SessionKeyCookie, SharedCookie);
            } 
                
            UserRoles = await GetUserRolesAsync(cookieContainer);
            //UserProfileInfo = await GetProfileInfoAsync(cookieContainer);
        }

        return Ok(result);
    }
}
```

This works fine, and when called from Postman - returns true.

However when calling the following IsLoggedIn() method, it always returns false:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> IsLoggedIn()
    {
        bool result = false;

        var operationContextScope = new OperationContextScope(AuthenticationServiceClient.InnerChannel);
        //var prop = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
        //SharedCookie = HttpContext.Session.GetString(SessionKeyCookie);
        //prop.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, SharedCookie);
        //OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties.Add(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, prop);
        
        using (operationContextScope)
        {
            try
            {
                result = await AuthenticationServiceClient.IsLoggedInAsync();
                
               
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex?.Message);
                if (ex.InnerException != null)
                    _logger.LogError(ex.InnerException.Message);
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
            }

            return Ok(result);
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure what I am missing. Any help is greately appreciated.

I tried adding "allowCookies=true" to the basicHttpBinding in the web.config in the legacy application, however that causes errors like "Internal Server Error".

Maybe I need to pass ClientCredentials to the IsLoggedIn() method.

Not sure what else to try. Thanks!

Comment: Well, it seems that this post: https://www.ben-morris.com/using-the-wcf-authentication-service-without-cookies/ answers my question. Thanks!